# Undefined object error when changing the object where i added 'onclick' event

Tags: javascript

So i wrote a function in javascript where if i click on a row from my table i get the number of the row and the 2 values of my cells into 2 input type boxes so i can edit them.

**What i want** is only to be able to do that when i click on a small icon (every row has this small icon as a third cell) , instead of the entire row.

The script is working until i change the part where the row is clicked with the small icon being clicked and i get undefined object error. I've tested the query selector in console and is working.

```
function selectedRowToInput() {
  var rIndex;
  var table = document.getElementById("tabel-taguri");

  for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++)
  {
    console.log(table.rows[i]);
    table.rows[i].onclick =  function(){           <- this is working
    table.rows[i].querySelector("td:nth-child(3)").onclick = function(){           <- not working

      //get the selected row index
      rIndex = this.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById("fname").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("fvalue").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
      globalVar = rIndex;
      console.log(globalVar);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add the click handler to the button instead of entire row

Comment: I cant do that because i still need to specify here on which action should the function trigger.